# Need help to parse mbox file and store certain attributes into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mbox

I have an mbox file containing my gmail messages. I would like to parse the file and import certain attributes and its values into my mysql database. Is there a way to do this? Need some suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ["mbox format"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) is essentially a bunch of email messages concatenated together.  If Ruby doesn't have a library for parsing the format, you can parse it manually by simply splitting the file on each line starting with the word "From ", then undoing any "From "-quoting within each message.  This will leave you with a collection of emails.

Parsing emails is left as an exercise for the student.